# Is this just very unlikely? Or is it impossible

Tags: python, random

So, I'm a beginner in python (coding in general, really), and I've tried to make this little program which generates a random number of `rods` in 305 attempts

```
import random
rods = 0
def blazerods():
    global rods
    seed = random.randint(0, 100000000000)
    random.seed(seed)
    i = 0
    rods = 0
    for i in range(0, 305):
        rnd = random.random()
        if rnd < 0.50:
            rods += 1
    print(rods)
    return rods


while 1==1:
    blazerods()
    if rods >= 211:
        break
```

The goal is to get 211 or more rods. However, I ran the program for 30 minutes without results.

My questions are: Is it even possible to get 211 or higher with just this code I included?

Can I make it more likely that rods can be more than 211 (still being a very unlikely result, ofc) without changing the chance(50%)?

Is `random.seed(seed)` even useful?

Comment: Note that `randint` also depends on the seed, so once you've seeded `random`, it will always progress in the same order… You shouldn't need to seed `random`, unless you have a specific reason to.

Comment: The expected average is 305 * 0.5 = 152. If you run it enough times you may get 211 or even 305 in some run.

Comment: @deceze alright, got it. I had noticed a pattern so i figured random.seed could help, may have just been a case

Comment: If this ever did reach 211, it'd probably mean `random` has a severe bias. It's not impossible that some chunk of results from `random` biases towards < .5, but if it's any good it should probably average out so that it's quite rare to reach 211 with this code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The probability distribution of rods is Binomial(305,0.5), that is the probability of getting exactly n rods is (305 choose n) * 0.5^305.

To get the probability to get at least 211, you need to sum these terms from 211 to 305. [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20%28305%20choose%20n%29%20*%200.5%5E305%2C%20n%3D211..305) gives that as 8.8e-12.

So... it is really, really unlikely and you will have to wait a long time.
If your loop runs 1000 times a second, you will expect to have enough rods about once every 4 years.

If I remember correctly, Matt Parker from the Youtube channel Stand-up Maths has something to say about this particular case in his video ["How lucky is too lucky"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Ko3TdPy0TU).

Comment: Yeah, figured it was unlikely, but I thought my code was just unable to get a result higher than 211. That's what I get for not being patient, I guess

Comment: Nobody is that patient =)

Comment: Once every 4 years, wow. I'm surprised because this actually happened once to the minecraft speedrunner Dream. That's where the 211/305 comes from. Now I know how lucky this really is lol

Comment: @simo Allegedly happened once for Dream. That is the point of the video by Matt Parker.

Comment: @scotty3785 I'll make sure to watch it

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Jens, this is easy to calculate via the [Binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).  The [SciPy stats module](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html) allows you to calculate this by doing:

```
from scipy import stats

# i.e. 305 draws with equal probability
d = stats.binom(305, 0.5)

# the probability of seeing something greater than this value
p = d.sf(210)
```

which should give you the same value as Jens got: ~8.8e-12.

Next we can use the `datetime` module to convert this number into the [expected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) time you have to wait:

```
from datetime import timedelta

time_per_try = timedelta(seconds=1/1000)

print(time_per_try / p)
```

which should give you ~1300 days, or 3.6 years.  Technically, this is the time you'll have to wait to have a 50% chance of seeing it, and it could appear much sooner or later.

You can calculate reasonable values of when this would happen, using the [negative binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution).  In Python, this looks like:

```
for q in stats.nbinom(1, p).ppf([0.025, 0.975]):
    print(time_per_try * q)
```

where the 0.025 and 0.975 values give you the 95% confidence interval you hear scientists talking about.

It tells you that if you had 20 computers running your algorithm in parallel, each doing 1000 tests per second, you could expect the first one to finish in around a month while the slowest one would likely be going on for more than 10 years.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Now that I know I will for sure use this library